# How to remove the red link border only from \gls in the package glossaries-extra?

Tags: hyperref, symbols, glossaries-extra, glossary

In the package `glossaries-extra` to get a Symbols list with the page numbers following the description of the symbol you need to use the `\gls{label}` command in the first (or in the cases in which you want the simbol to be referenced in the Symbols list) appearance of such a symbol, but this makes the PDF file show a horrible red rectangle emcompassing the symbol, of couse I could simply use `\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}` in the preamble, but that would make all hyperlinks lose the red rectangle, and I don't want that, I wanted only the `\gls{label}` instances to lose the red rectangle, something like a command that I could use locally such as a `\NoRedRectangle{\gls{label}}`, or a option for `glossaries-extra` that does this, is there any such thing?

Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[symbols,nogroupskip,sort=use,automake]{glossaries-extra}

\makeglossaries

\begin{document}
\newglossaryentry{Sd}{name={\ensuremath{S_\dagger}},sort={Sd},description={The self-adjoint part of a subset from a $C^*$-algebra $\hspace{0.3pt}$, $\hspace{2pt}$},type={symbols}}\gls{Sd}

\newpage
\printglossary[type=symbols,title={Symbols List}]
\thispagestyle{plain}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can change the border locally. Provide a small but complete example that one can use to test the code.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer there, i just edited the question with a minimal example, can you help me now?

Comment: If you don't want link, then donot use `hyperref`

Answer (score 1):

Using `\setkeys{glslink}{hyper=false}` after `\usepackage{glossaries-extra}` disables linking of glossary entries, which also removes the red hyperref border.